# Why doesn't GoBackAsync() fire on OnNavigatedTo() method of previous page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism

I have two pages *pageA* and *pageB*.

When I navigate from *pageA* to *pageB* and later execute `_navigationService.GoBackAsync()`, it works correctly and it navigates me to *pageA*.

But, `OnNavigatedTo()` and `OnNavigatingTo()` in *pageA* doesn't seem to execute (that I can tell?). *PageA* is a tabbedPage and I'm using Xamarin forms and Prism 7.

I'm testing it on iPhone.

What could I be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

That (what you have) should work. You have found a bug.

Please [submit your issue to the Prism GitHub site](https://github.com/prismlibrary/prism/issues) and provide as much information as possible as well as a sample app that reproduces the issue.

Comment: [Meta discussion here, about this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362872/owners-officials-for-a-tag).

Comment: @ChrisNevill There shouldn't be a difference. *That should work* isn't really an answer, and SO isn't a support forum. It's a Q&A site. See the discussion in the meta above.

Comment: @FrankerZ While the answer could go on to detail what sort of behavior could be measured for someone else to be sure it was a bug, it's a perfectly valid answer. If someone posted "GCC says 1+1 = 3" then the answer is "That's wrong, and a bug in GCC, here's where you can file a bug".  But this isn't the place to have that discussion, there's a [meta thread about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362872/owners-officials-for-a-tag).